# Unable to create a dropdownlist(child navigation) on my existing navbar.

Tags: asp.net, css, navbar

Initially i have a navbar which is working fine with my hover. However after progressing with my work, i realized i have too many things to add into my navbar which results it to become very long, hence i took of the child navigation bar/dropdownlist. This is basically how my navbar look like

[image]

In order to be like this, this is how my css look like

```
#navbarwidth {
width:70%;
position:fixed;
text-align: center;
flex-align:center;
margin:0%;
top:20%;
left:15%;
}

#nav {
background: #292929;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-stop(4%, #3c3c3c), to(#292929));
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:70px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
border: 1px yellow;
border-bottom: none;
width:100%;
}
#nav li a, #nav li {
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
min-width: 60px;
}
#nav li {
list-style: none;
}
#nav li a {
padding: 1em 2em;
text-decoration: none;
color: #5FFB17;
border-right: 0px solid #3c3c3c;
border-left: 0px solid #292929;
border-bottom: 0px solid #232323;
border-top: 0px solid #545454;
}
#nav li a:hover {

background: #2a0d65;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11032e, #2a0d65);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#11032e),  to(#2a0d65));
}
```

My source looks like this

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="AdminAddAccount.aspx">Add Account</a></li>
<li><a href="AdminDropAccount.aspx">Drop Account</a></li>   
<li><a href="AdminEditProfile.aspx">Edit Account</a></li>
<li><a href="AdminColdStorage.aspx">Cold Account</a></li>   
<li><a href="AdminReportCheck.aspx">Report Check</a></li>
<li><a href="AdminLogout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

In order to let it produce a child navbar i added this according to my research

```
#nav ul{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
padding:0;
margin:0;
top:30px;
}
```

I also changed my source accordingly

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
<li><a href="AdminAddAccount.aspx">Add</a></li>
<li><a href="AdminDropAccount.aspx">Drop</a></li>   
<li><a href="AdminEditProfile.aspx">Edit</a></li>
<li><a href="AdminColdStorage.aspx">Cold</a></li>   
</ul>
<ul><li><a href="AdminReportCheck.aspx">Report Check</a></li></ul>
<ul><li><a href="AdminLogout.aspx">Logout</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

And end up my entire navbar disappear. I'm quite confused with it. So i'm wondering how do i do a dropdownlist on my existing navbar.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding all #nav ul. Remove visibility:hidden from this style:

```
#nav ul{
position:absolute;
/*visibility:hidden;*/
padding:0;
margin:0;
top:30px;
}
```

You can look at simple CSS dropdown menu, there are many example available. [Here](http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/)'s one. Or even using jquery plugin you can create very nice menu with animation.